# Mirror backup WAMP folder into external hard drive

Tags: wamp, backup, mirroring

I got Seagate Backup Plus Slim 1TB today.

I am planning to do mirror backup of my web projects from pc (C:\wamp46\www) to external drive (E:).

The toolkit app created folders on C:\ and E:\ both named "Mirror" as the syncing folder. Tested it and it works well.

But [Seagate](https://www.seagate.com/manuals/software/toolkit/mirror-folders/#create-a-mirror-plan) says:

> The Mirror folders must each be named “**Mirror**” in order to sync. **Do not rename** the folders.

Now, how can I mirror backup my files under "www" folders if I can't rename "www" folder?

Is there any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So try to rename WAMP root folder from `C:\wamp46\www`  to `C:\Mirror`

Edit the `httpd.conf` file and/or the `vhosts.conf` file for the site wish to change. The Directory directive will let you specify where the files for this site are to be located.

For more info on httpd.conf see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html

And specifically: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: I see this on httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf: "${INSTALL_DIR}/www", so I'll change it to "C:/Mirror" directly?

Comment: Something like this: DocumentRoot c:/Mirror/www

Comment: ok got it.. will backup the files first then i'll give it a go. thanks!